# React State Management: Context API as global store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am working on a React webapplication with TypeScript.
I want to set up State Management with React Hooks and Context API and found this cool, easy and short [tutorial](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c).

I followed the tutorial, but my compiler shows couple of errors. I think that are basic type errors, that I don't get (I am more used to JavaScript than TypeScript).

My State Context:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export interface IState {
  isAuth: boolean;
  user: string;
}

interface IContextProps {
  state: IState;
  dispatch: ({ type }: { type: string }) => void;
}

export const StateContext = createContext({} as IContextProps);
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

My State Reducer:

```
import { initialState } from './InitialState';

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setObj':
      return {
        ...state,
        obj: action.objValue,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My Initial State:

```
import { emptyObj } from '../interfaces/IObj';

export const initialState = {
  obj: emptyObj,
};
```

My App:

```
import React from 'react';

import { StateProvider } from './utils/StateContext';

import { initialState } from './globals/constants/InitialState';
import { reducer } from './globals/constants/StateReducer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </StateProvider>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The errors are only in the State Context File:

1.) State Context
First error is the State Context. In the tutorial it's defined as:
`export const StateContext = createContext();`
And the compiler throws an error.
If I use `export const StateContext = createContext(undefined);`, then the error is gone.
Also if I use (like described at beginning) `export const StateContext = createContext({} as IContextProps);` and add interfaces IState and IContextProps then it also works. I guess that part is fine for now.

2.) State Provider
`export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => ...`  The compiler throws for reducer, initialState and children the same error: **Binding Element [reducer / initialState / children] has implicitly any type.**

3.) value
`value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>...` The compiler cries:
**Type '[unknown, DispatchWithoutAction]' is not assignable to type 'IContextProps'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(335, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps'**

Thanks in advance for any help. If you need more informations then let me know.

Comment: 1) The `createContext` function requires a default in the case that someone attempts to consume it outside of a provider. As you noted this could just be undefined or an empty object, but it is a requirement. 2) This is a part of Typescript (it can be turned off) but it is telling you that it cannot infer the types of reducer, inititalState and children. You will have to change your code so that it can infer them or manually type them. 3) `useReducer` has not been able to infer the type for your state (shown by the unknown), a way to fix this might be to type your initial state to IState.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be because of the

`<StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>`

useReducer returns an array and Provider expects an object.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducers, initialState);
return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
       {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);
```

I have written an article on the same you can that

Article: [State Management with React Hooks and Context API](https://devsmitra.medium.com/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-2968a5cf5c83)

Running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue recently and i solved it this way, i hope it helps you as well. i updated your code as shown in the following snippets,

```
export interface IState {
    user: any,
    theme: boolean,
    drawer: boolean,
}

export const initialState = {
    user: null,
    theme: false,
    drawer: false,
}

export enum actionTypes {
    SET_THEME = "SET_THEME",
    SET_USER = "SET_USER",
    OPEN_DRAWER = "OPEN_DRAWER",
}

export type IAction =
    | {
        type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
        value: any
    } | {
        type: actionTypes.SET_THEME,
        value: boolean
    }| {
        type: actionTypes.OPEN_DRAWER,
        value: boolean
    }

const reducer = (state: IState, action:IAction): IState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_THEME:
            return {
                ...state,
                theme: action.value,
            }
        case actionTypes.SET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.value,
            }
        case actionTypes.OPEN_DRAWER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.value,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

The context provider (StateProvider) should be updated to...

```
import React, {useReducer, createContext, useContext, ReactElement} from 'react';
import {initialState, IState} from "./Reducer";

const StateContext = createContext<IState | any>(initialState);

interface StateProps{
    children: ReactElement,
    initialState: (IState | any),
    reducer: (IState | any),
}

export const StateProvider = ({children,initialState, reducer }: StateProps): ReactElement => {
    // const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(initialState, reducer);
    return(
        <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(initialState, reducer)}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Then wrap your main app with the context provider (StateProvider)

```
import {HeadTag, Layout} from "../components/components";
import reducer, {initialState} from "../provider/Reducer";
import {StateProvider} from "../provider/StateProvider";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
      <>
          <HeadTag />
          <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer} >
              <Layout>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
              </Layout>
          </StateProvider>
      </>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

Consuming it in your app

```
/* data layer */
    const [{user, theme, drawer}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);


    /* switch between dark and light mode */
    const handleTheme = () => {
        if(theme){
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SET_THEME,
                value: false,
            });
        }else{
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SET_THEME,
                value: true,
            });
        }
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.